# Group Policy to disable Printer Preferences

Tags: windows, group-policy, domain, printing

Can someone please advise on how we can disable users being able to open Printer Preferences on network printers that they have added to their computers?

We have deployed around 100 new printers with predefined agreed settings (such as duplex printing on all printers), but there are some clever users who are just adding the new printers and then opening Printer Preferences to change anything that they don't like.

Comment: It sounds to me like they have too many permissions on the print queues themselves.

Comment: Hmm sorry, can you explain?

Comment: It sounds like they have "manage printer" permissions.  They probably only need print, with creator/owner having "manage documents."

Comment: @KatherineVillyard even with just print right, some settings are often not locked in the general's tab. (those are settings stored in the user profile for each users)

Answer (score 1):

It's too granular for Microsoft. The print driver can lock certain feature, but it all depend on the print driver used. (as it's the print driver that can block advanced feature, as Microsoft only allow or not a user to the printer)

Like some ricoh can block the color's usage and ask a password.

A workaround I suggest is that GPO:

User Configuration--> Administrative Templates --> Control Panel --> Printers --> Prevent addition of printers --> Enable

If you use GPP in example to deploy your printer, please set it to replace. It will replace existing setting at each GPO refresh's interval. (by default 90 minutes)

> Delete and recreate the shared printer connection. The net result of
>   the **Replace action overwrites all existing settings** associated with
>   the shared printer connection. If the shared printer connection does
>   not exist, then the Replace action creates a new shared printer
>   connection.

In the end, you will block the user to add printer, and each printer added will refresh themselves automatically.

Answer (score -2):

as the users are able to change the printer preferences, they seem to have the "manage printer" permission. Usually they should only have "print documents".
The general setting can be changed under the advanced tab. Without the manage printer permission, the user is not able to change this on the print server.
Then it is only possible under the user's preferences.

And maybe good to know, as an additon, you could restrict and manage the printers via our software, the ThinPrint Engine. As you can there set defaults that cannot be changed by the user, not depending which permissions the users have on the printer.

Have a look at www.thinprint.com

Comment: The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam, as just happened with your answer. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay.  See the [policy](http://serverfault.com/help/promotion) on our help pages. -|- I don't think your post is in complete violation and although your answer/explanation sounds plausible, it could also be improved though.