# Prevent users from changing printer preferences

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, network-printer

I am trying to find a way to lock down users from changing their default settings on their machines joined to a domain. Users tend to set colored as their default after network print driver has been installed on their machines :(

I looked at many forums and 2 ways that got stuck on my mind as an option:

```
Way 1 which i obtained from a forum that dates to 2006 
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21820852/Prevent-Users-to-change-Printer-Preferences-Property.html
```

A guy called Merete suggested the following

Here is how to do it Using the the Windows Resource Editor. Warning attempt this at your own risk. 
Back up first
then  edit the following file in the Windows System32 folder. 
COMDLG32.DLL

Edit the following Dialog Resources.

100 - 1033 
101 - 1033 
1538 - 1033

Disable the Preferences button by right clicking it, select Edit control and set the WS_DISABLE style.

Save the COMDLG32.DLL.

This all straight and swell but after downloading resource hacker and locating that DLL i didn't find the numbers he was implying

```
Way 2 was by this fellow "yagmoth555" in this link
http://serverfault.com/questions/747339/group-policy-to-disable-printer-preferences#
```

That stated using group policy will help do that as well, by a synch timer that ensures default settings get reinstated after they have been changed, which defeats the purpose of locking this :(

Is there any way that i can bluntly lock "Printer Preferences" keeping in my mind we have a collection of printers from different vendors like HP plotter and Ricoh multi purpose and OCE plotter/scanner

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To add to my other answer you link [to](https://serverfault.com/questions/747339/group-policy-to-disable-printer-preferences#), as your question is less specific on only GPP;

Get enterprise grad printer is the easiest option. You can block the color usage by forcing PIN or alternative authentication mean. Some printer the driver will ask the pin, other its at the printer itselft that you will need to unlock your printout.

If you cant, second option is to publish a printer in black&white only. In the main tab you remove the color usage. Depending on the driver usually its enought to block them. That tip is easily bypassable if the user manually add the printer to its computer. You could use a GPP in modify mode for the published printer  and to be sure no option are kept you could delete the printer connection before adding them.